# Call paint method from game loop at the start of a button

Tags: java, swing

Hi I'm trying to call the paint method every time in a game loop.At the moment the screen pops up with a label and a button once the button has been pressed the label and button go which i want but i can't get the paint method to start i tried j.repaint() & j.validate() neither accessed paint method.Any help would be appreciated.

```
package sgame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SGame extends JPanel
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        final JFrame window = new JFrame("hello");
        final JPanel window1 = new JPanel();
        Timer loop = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                GameLoop(window1);

            }
        });
        Window(window, loop);

    }

    public static void Window(final JFrame window, final Timer loop)
    {
        final JButton b1 = new JButton("GO!");
        b1.setLocation(210, 300);
        b1.setSize(70, 50);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(500, 500);
        window.setLocation(420, 170);
        window.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        final JLabel Title = new JLabel("Snake", JLabel.CENTER);
        Title.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 60));
        Title.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        Title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        window.add(b1);
        window.add(Title);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() // runs when buttons pressed
            {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) // clears header,button and starts timer
                {
                    b1.invalidate();
                    b1.setVisible(false);
                    Title.setVisible(false);
                    Title.invalidate();
                    loop.start();
                }

            });

    }

    public static void GameLoop(JPanel j)
    {
        // Call paint method
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.drawRect(30, 30, 30, 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should almost never call the paint method directly, and certainly not for this situation. Your code is a bit heavy on the static variables and methods which suggests that redesign is in order. Also, where do you create an SGame instance? The paintComponent will have no meaning if no instance of SGame is created and displayed in a top level window. Have you gone through the tutorials yet? Consider going through some tutorials first including the Swing tutorials.

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1):

The `paintComponent()` method in `SGame` is never called because you didn't instanciate any SGame object. And window1 has not been added to the frame.

Something like this should be better :

```
public class SGame extends JPanel {

    private Timer loop;

    public SGame(){
        loop = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                gameLoop();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame window = new JFrame("hello");
        final JButton b1 = new JButton("GO!");
        b1.setLocation(210, 300);
        b1.setSize(70, 50);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(500, 500);
        window.setLocation(420, 170);
        window.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        final JLabel Title = new JLabel("Snake", JLabel.CENTER);
        Title.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.ITALIC, 60));
        Title.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        Title.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        window.add(b1);
        window.add(Title);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // runs when buttons pressed
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) // clears header,button
            {
                b1.invalidate();
                b1.setVisible(false);
                Title.setVisible(false);
                Title.invalidate();
                SGame sg = new SGame();
                window.add(sg);
                sg.start();
            }
        });;
    }

    public void start(){
        loop.start();
    }

    public void gameLoop() {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.drawRect(30, 30, 30, 30);
    }
}
```